# extract irregular numeric data from strings

Tags: r, regex, string

I have data like below.  I wish to extract the first and last year from each string here called `my.string`.  Some strings only contain one year and some strings contain no years.  No strings contain more than two years.  I have provided the desired result in the object named `desired.result` below the example data set.  I am using `R`.

When a string contains two years those years are contained within a portion of the string that looks like this `ga49.51` or `ea22.24`

When a string contains only one year that year is contained in a portion of the string that looks like this: `time11`

I know a bit about `regex`, but this problem seems too irregular and complex for me to figure out.  I am not even sure where to begin.  Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT**

Perhaps delete the numbers before the first colon (:) and the remaining numbers are what I want.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

                my.string  cov1 cov2

           42:Alpha:ga6.8  -0.1  2.2
          43:Alpha:ga9.11  -2.5  0.6
         44:Alpha:ga30.32  -1.3  0.5
         45:Alpha:ga49.51  -2.5  0.6
   50:Alpha:time1:ga.time  -1.7  0.9
   51:Alpha:time2:ga.time  -1.5  0.8
   52:Alpha:time3:ga.time  -1.0  1.0
             2:Beta:ea2.9  -1.7  0.6
           3:Beta:ea17.19  -5.0  0.8
           4:Beta:ea22.24  -6.4  1.0
                8:Beta:as   0.2  0.6
                9:Beta:sd   1.7  0.4
     12:Beta:time1:ea.tim  -2.6  1.8
     13:Beta:time10:ea.ti  -3.6  1.1
     14:Beta:time11:ea.ti  -3.1  0.7

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

desired.result <- read.table(text = '

                my.string  cov1 cov2  time1  time2

           42:Alpha:ga6.8  -0.1  2.2      6      8
          43:Alpha:ga9.11  -2.5  0.6      9     11
         44:Alpha:ga30.32  -1.3  0.5     30     32
         45:Alpha:ga49.51  -2.5  0.6     49     51
   50:Alpha:time1:ga.time  -1.7  0.9      1     NA
   51:Alpha:time2:ga.time  -1.5  0.8      2     NA
   52:Alpha:time3:ga.time  -1.0  1.0      3     NA
             2:Beta:ea2.9  -1.7  0.6      2      9
           3:Beta:ea17.19  -5.0  0.8     17     19
           4:Beta:ea22.24  -6.4  1.0     22     24
                8:Beta:as   0.2  0.6     NA     NA
                9:Beta:sd   1.7  0.4     NA     NA
     12:Beta:time1:ea.tim  -2.6  1.8      1     NA
     13:Beta:time10:ea.ti  -3.6  1.1     10     NA
     14:Beta:time11:ea.ti  -3.1  0.7     11     NA

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")
```

Comment: What programming language or scripting language are you using to process your text file?

Comment: Can you show an example of your hoped-for output based on your sample input? which part of `ga49.51` is the year? Which part of `time11` is the year (I am guessing `11`)?

Comment: `((?:time|ga|ea)(?<time1>\d+)(\.(?<time2>\d+))?)`

Comment: `read.table(text = gsub('\\D+|^\\d+', ' ', my.data$my.string), fill = TRUE)`

Comment: I am using R.  The object `desired.result` contains the desired result.

Comment: @rawr your answer comes close but does not handle strings with no years.

Comment: @RobertMcKee your suggestion might work, but I am unclear how to apply it to my data set

Comment: @MarkMiller sorry was trying to do it quickly, just add `blank.lines.skip = FALSE`,  so try `read.table(text = gsub('\\D+|^\\d+', ' ', my.data$my.string), fill = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE)`

Comment: @rawr Very nice.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.  I like base `R` solutions.

Comment: Did any of the answers below work for you? Please consider accepting the one that best worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *stringr* library to extract the data you need since it handles NA values better, and also allows using a *constrained-width* lookbehind:

```
> library(stringr)
> my.data$time1 <- str_extract(my.data$my.string, "(?<=time)\\d+|(?<=\\b[ge]a)\\d+")
> my.data$time2 <- str_extract(my.data$my.string, "(?<=\\b[ge]a\\d{1,100}\\.)\\d+")
> my.data
                my.string cov1 cov2 time1 time2
1          42:Alpha:ga6.8 -0.1  2.2     6     8
2         43:Alpha:ga9.11 -2.5  0.6     9    11
3        44:Alpha:ga30.32 -1.3  0.5    30    32
4        45:Alpha:ga49.51 -2.5  0.6    49    51
5  50:Alpha:time1:ga.time -1.7  0.9     1  <NA>
6  51:Alpha:time2:ga.time -1.5  0.8     2  <NA>
7  52:Alpha:time3:ga.time -1.0  1.0     3  <NA>
8            2:Beta:ea2.9 -1.7  0.6     2     9
9          3:Beta:ea17.19 -5.0  0.8    17    19
10         4:Beta:ea22.24 -6.4  1.0    22    24
11              8:Beta:as  0.2  0.6  <NA>  <NA>
12              9:Beta:sd  1.7  0.4  <NA>  <NA>
13   12:Beta:time1:ea.tim -2.6  1.8     1  <NA>
14   13:Beta:time10:ea.ti -3.6  1.1    10  <NA>
15   14:Beta:time11:ea.ti -3.1  0.7    11  <NA>
```

The first regex matches:

- `(?<=time)\\d+` - 1+ digits that have `time` before them
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\\b[ge]a)\\d+` - 1+ digits that have `ge` or ea` as a whole word in front

The second regex matches:

- `(?<=\\b[ge]a\\d{1,100}\\.)` - check if the current position is preceded with `ge` or `ea` as a whole word followed with 1 to 100 digits (I believe that should be enough for your scenario, 100-digit chunks are hardly expected here, you may even decrease the value), and then a `.`
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that will extract either of the two types, and output them to different columns at the end of the lines:

Search: `.*(?:time(\d+)|(?:[ge]a)(\d+)\.(\d+)).*`

Replace: `$0\t$1\t$2\t$3`

**Breakdown:**

- `.*(?:` ... `).*` ensures that the whole line is matched, and uses a non-capturing group for the main alternation
- `time(\d+)`: this is the first half of the alternation, capturing any digits after a "time"
- `(?:[ge]a)(\d+)\.(\d+)`: the second half of the alternation matches "ga" or "ea" followed by two sets of digits, each in its own capture group
- Replacement: `$0` puts the whole line back. Each of the other capture groups are added, with tabs in-between.

[See regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/EvhAi9/1)